# Cross-referencing in XML documentation comments

Tags: delphi, xml-documentation

When using XML Documentation Comments, I can't figure out how I can refer to another class member. Take this code:

```
TGreeter = class

  ///  <summary>Says hello</summary>
  procedure Hello;

  ///  <summary>Says hello to all</summary>
  ///  <remarks>
  ///   This is the same as <see cref="Hello"/>, but it says hello to all
  ///   instead.
  ///  </remarks>
  procedure HelloAll;

end;
```

Help Insight displays the help for `HelloAll` fine, but if I click on the link to `Hello` it does nothing (almost nothing; the mouse pointer indicates that, for a second or so, it does some thinking, but then it stops). What is the correct way to make such a cross-reference?

Comment: It does some thinking for a second ? You're the lucky one :) It often takes ages (seen in many versions I've worked with). Actually, I've never seen DI working properly yet. Though I'm using it with a hope that one day someone comes with working IDE integration.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering myself for quite a long time before I found a syntax that works (tested with Delphi XE4): You need to put the unit name, a pipe, the class name, a point and then method name.

In your example, let's say that the unit is called "MyUnit", then you should use:

```
<see cref="MyUnit|TGreeter.Hello"/>
```